# Why ar_track_alvar is not installing?

Tags: ros, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to install the ar_track_alvar using **sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar**
I was getting the following error.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar**

I also tried using synaptic tool which is alternative to apt-get install. But i was not able to find indigo related alvar packages
[image: image description]

Can anyone please help me on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241399/why-ar_track_alvar-is-not-installing?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-09**:
ar_track_alvar is listed as released for Indigo, so that should work if you're using Indigo that was installed through apt on Ubuntu x86. Perhaps you're using a different OS or a different CPU?

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-08-09**:
Here is my OS details

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-09**:
The [build status page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=alvar) and the [arm build status page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_arm.html?q=alvar) show that ar_track_alvar is built and stable for Ubuntu Trusty x86, amd64 and armhf architectures,

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-09**:
Did you install ROS through apt or from source? Are your apt sources set up correctly?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-09**:
Your system reports that it's running Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty), but the ROS packages listed are for Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise). Did you have a previous version of ROS installed? Did you upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu?

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-08-09**:
ROS was installed through apt-get   
 rosversion -d  
 indigo

**Comment by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on 2016-08-09**:
Thank you so much for your support, i re-installed the ros indigo keys.  i was able to install the ar_track_alvar now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed 1.2 and 1.3 from this link  http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu
and sudo apt-get update

above steps worked for me, now i was able to install

---

Originally posted by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) with karma: 75 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0